# DRF does not work with wagtail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I have used DRF for rest api and puput for blog which is built on top of the wagtail. Before using puput, my rest api used to work but not now. For example when i try to open the url **http://localhost:8000/rest-api/ui/tab/** i get following error

> Page not Found 404 error Raised by:   wagtail.wagtailcore.views.serve

**settings.py**

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    # rest framework
    'rest_framework',

    # third party apps
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'ckeditor',
]

MACHINA_APPS = [
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_markdown',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'ui_mgmt',                # UI manager - tabs, cards etc
    'faq',                    # faq
]

PUPUT_APPS = [
    'wagtail.wagtailcore',
    'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
    'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
    'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
    'wagtail.wagtailusers',
    'wagtail.wagtailimages',
    'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
    'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
    'wagtail.wagtailsites',
    'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
    'wagtail.wagtailforms',
    'wagtail.contrib.wagtailsitemaps',
    'wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage',
    'compressor',
    'taggit',
    'modelcluster',
    'puput',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + MACHINA_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + get_machina_apps() + PUPUT_APPS
```

**urls.py**

```
from ui_mgmt import urls as ui_mgmt_urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include(allauth_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^forum/', include(board.urls)),
    url(r'', include('puput.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^rest-api/', include(ui_mgmt_urls)),
]
```

**ui_mgmt/urls.py**

```
url(r'^ui/tabs/$', tab_list, name='tab_list'),
```

**ui_mgmt/views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def tab_list(request, format=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tabs = Tab.objects.filter(belongsTo=user)
        serialized_data = ExtendedTabSerializer(tabs, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serialized_data = TabSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            serialized_data.save(belongsTo=user)
            newTab = ExtendedTabSerializer(Tab.objects.get(id=serialized_data.data['id']))
            return Response(newTab.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serialized_data.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Why my DRF is not working? I get the same error for every rest api call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the order of your url patterns.. puput should (probablly) the last element

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^accounts/', include(allauth_urls)),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^forum/', include(board.urls)),
  url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
  url(r'^rest-api/', include(ui_mgmt_urls)),
  url(r'', include('puput.urls')),  # it will match the rest of patterns
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you tell me why putting it in the last works?

Comment: [Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

puput must have a greedy regex, i.e.  `(r'.*', pageview)` or something like that